# complicated sql query returning empty result

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, join

My database looks like this

```
tickets table
-------------
ticket_id
title
description
department_id
status_id
priority_id
assignee_id
creator_id

departments table
------------------
dep_id
dep_name

status table
------------
status_id
status_name

priority table
---------------
pr_id
pr_name

users table
-----------
u_id
username
password
salt
email
firstName
lastName
department_id
userlevel_id

userlevels table
-----------------
ul_id
ul_name
```

I need to load all tickets given the asignee id. My query looks like this

```
SQLQuery q = q.createSQLQuery("SELECT t.*,d.*,s.*,p.*,u.*,a.* FROM tickets t, departments d, status s, priority p, users u, attachments a WHERE t.department_id=d.dep_id AND t.status_id=s.stat_id AND t.priority_id=p.pr_id AND t.assignee_id=u.u_id AND t.creator_id=u.u_id AND t.tick_id=a.ticket_id AND assignee_id=?");

    q.setInt(0, some_valid_assignee_id);
    List<Object> result = q.list();
```

But it's returning an empty object list. Can anyone point me in the right direction, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you have `AND t.assignee_id = u.u_id`and also `AND t.creator_id = u.u_id`.  The only way that would return any records is if the `assignee_id` and `creator_id` were the same.  I think what you really need to do is link to the `users` table twice like so:

```
SELECT t.*, d.*, s.*, p.*, u1.*, u2.*, a.* 
FROM tickets t
  INNER JOIN departments d ON t.department_id = d.dep_id 
  INNER JOIN status s ON t.status_id = s.stat_id 
  INNER JOIN priority p ON t.priority_id = p.pr_id 
  INNER JOIN users u1 ON t.assignee_id = u.u_id 
  INNER JOIN users u2 ON t.creator_id = u.u_id 
  INNER JOIN attachments a ON t.tick_id = a.ticket_id 
WHERE assignee_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper join syntax . . . makes the query easier to read and to write.

However, I'm guessing that the problem is:

```
t.assignee_id = u.u_id AND t.creator_id = u.u_id
```

That would assume that

```
t.assignee_id = t.creator_id
```

Perhaps this never happens in your data.